# Using two of the same functions (Cannot redeclare class)

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

In the following code, I created two functions that needs the same information. I'm using [this script](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query).

```
<?php 
function get_cbMain_Query() {
  define( 'Main_SERVER_ADDR', 'ip');
  define( 'Main_SERVER_PORT', 25565);
  define( 'Main_TIMEOUT', 1 );

  // require bloginfo('template_url') . 'inc/avatars/MinecraftQuery.class.php';
  require __DIR__ . '/mcQuery/MinecraftQuery.class.php';

  // Display everything in browser, because some people can't look in logs for errors
  Error_Reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
  Ini_Set( 'display_errors', true );

  $Timer = MicroTime( true );
  $Query = new MinecraftQuery( );

  try
  {
    $Query->Connect( Main_SERVER_ADDR, Main_SERVER_PORT, Main_TIMEOUT );
  }
  catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
  {
    $Error = $e->getMessage();
   echo 'error. <br>'. $Error;
  }
  return $Query;
}

function get_cbTekkit_Query() {
  define( 'Tekkit_SERVER_ADDR', 'ip');
  define( 'Tekkit_SERVER_PORT', 25565);
  define( 'Tekkit_TIMEOUT', 1 );

  // require bloginfo('template_url') . 'inc/avatars/MinecraftQuery.class.php';
  require __DIR__ . '/mcQuery/MinecraftQuery.class.php';

  // Display everything in browser, because some people can't look in logs for errors
  Error_Reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
  Ini_Set( 'display_errors', true );

  $Timer = MicroTime( true );
  $Query = new MinecraftQuery( );

  try
  {
    $Query->Connect( Tekkit_SERVER_ADDR, Tekkit_SERVER_PORT, Tekkit_TIMEOUT );
  }
  catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
  {
    $Error = $e->getMessage();
   echo 'error. <br>'. $Error;
  }
  return $Query;
}
```

When using this script and do the following to call it (From a different page, this script is included in another)

```
          $cbMain = get_cbMain_Query();
          $cbTekkit = get_cbTekkit_Query();
```

Then I get:

```
 Cannot redeclare class MinecraftQueryException in MinecraftQuery.class.php on line 5
```

I am new to classes ad objects in PHP and can't figure out why i can't call two functions and use them at the same time. Help please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13879461/889949

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line in both functions

```
require __DIR__ . '/mcQuery/MinecraftQuery.class.php';
```

to read

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/mcQuery/MinecraftQuery.class.php';
```

This will ensure the file is included once, and avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

you either do `require_once` or `include_once` or you can put an

```
if(!function_exists('get_cbMain_Query')){... }
if(!function_exists('get_cbTekkit_Query')){... }
```

around each function to make sure they are only declared once.